# How to load a tensorflow .yaml config file now that model_from_yaml is depricated?

Tags: python, tensorflow, parsing, keras, yaml

I am trying to load an object detection model from the official [tensorflow model zoo](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/official/vision/MODEL_GARDEN.md). I have one problem however. They all seem to use the old config + checkpoint system. The config files are saved in .yaml format, but the [model_from_yaml](https://tf.keras.models.model_from_yaml) method is depricated and throwing an error.

I am trying to convert [this file](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/official/vision/configs/experiments/image_classification/imagenet_resnetrs152_i256.yaml). Converting to a json file and trying model_from_json results in the following error:

```
Exception has occurred: JSONDecodeError
Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)
StopIteration: 0
```

Trying to read the yaml file seperatly with this code also returns an error:

```
config = {}
with open("C:/Users/XXX/Downloads/resnet-rs-152-i256/imagenet_resnetrs152_i256.yaml", "r") as stream:
    try: config = yaml.safe_load(stream)
    except yaml.YAMLError as exc: print(exc)
loaded_model = tf.keras.models.model_from_config(config)

Exception has occurred: ValueError
Improper config format for {...}
Expecting python dict contains `class_name` and `config` as keys
```

Are the configs wrong? Is there no way to load any of these models?

Comment: Hey, did you a find a solution to this issue. I'm having the same issue. Conversion of the YAML file to JSON doesn't work. I think keras inserts custom lines in the file.

Comment: I ended up going with another model exported with save_model() instead

Answer (score -2):

You could try something like this using `tf.io.gfile.Gfile()`

```
import tensorflow as tf
import yaml
from tensorflow.keras.models import model_from_yaml

# Load YAML file
with tf.io.gfile.GFile('model.yaml', 'r') as yaml_file:
    yaml_string = yaml_file.read()

# Parse YAML string
model_yaml = yaml.safe_load(yaml_string)

# Load model architecture from YAML
model = model_from_yaml(model_yaml)

# Load model weights from HDF5 file
model.load_weights('model_weights.h5')
```

Or load the weights however else you have them, like:

```
# Load model weights from SavedModel directory
model.load_weights('saved_model_dir/variables/variables')
```